# Make python read 12 from file as 12 not 1 and 2

Tags: python, file, for-loop, numbers, readlines

Trying to make a program that provides the price to different numbers of stages. In "tripss.txt",third line is the number 12, python interprets it as 1 and 2 instead and gives the price for each rather than the number as a whole, any way to fix it to that it's read as 12?.

```
infile = open("tripss.txt","r")  
customer_one= infile.readline().strip("\n")     
customer_two= infile.readline().strip("\n")  
customer_three= infile.readline().strip("\n")      
one_to_three_stages="euro 1.55"   
four_to_seven_stages="euro 1.85"   
seven_to_eleven_stages="euro 2.45"  
more_than_eleven_stages="euro 2.85"  
cheapest = ["1","2","3"]       
cheap = ["4","5","6","7"]    
expensive = ["7","8","9","10","11"]     
    for number in customer_three:     
    if number in cheapest:   
        print one_to_three_stages    
    elif number in cheap:     
        print four_to_seven_stages    
    elif number in expensive:    
        print seven_to_eleven_stages   
    else:         
        print more_than_eleven_stages
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken. And you probably need to convert your string to an int (if that's what you want), or don't loop over a single string (that will give you each character one after the other).

Comment: Please supply example input. I think for instance that line 3 is just "12\n" from your comments but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems that you want to consider customer_three as a list of strings. However in your code it is a string, not a list of strings, and so the for loop iterates on the characters of the string ("1" and "2").
So I suggest you to replace:

```
customer_three= infile.readline().strip("\n")
```

with:

```
customer_three= infile.readline().strip("\n").split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You say *third line is the number 12* so after `customer_three= infile.readline().strip("\n")`, `customer_three` will be the string `"12"`. If you then start the for loop `for number in customer_three:`, `number` will be assigned each element of the string - first `"1"`, and then `"2"`.

The solution is simple. `customer_three` already has the string you want. Remove the `for` loop completely.